# Oracle SQL count col values

Tags: sql, oracle

my database looks like this:

```
+-----+----------+-----------+----------+
+ ID  +   col1   +   col2    +  col 3   +
+-----+----------+-----------+----------+
+  1  +    Y     +    N      +     Y    +
+-----+----------+-----------+----------+
```

What I want to have is the percantage of Y compared to N, e.g. Y = 2, N = 1 --> 75%

Can I do this in SQL?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, how do you get 75% from Y = 2, N = 1?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Y = 66.666600` and `N = 33.333300`

Comment: And also, can you only have Y/N in the columns? Is it possible to have null values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would case it like this:

```
select ID,
       floor((case when col1 = Y then 1 else 0 end +
              case when col2 = Y then 1 else 0 end +
              case when col3 = Y then 1 else 0 end)* 100 / 3) as pc_Y
from MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Decode can do it. But as already asked what about `NULL` values in comments, I am providing under assumption that NULL can exist and it is possible to have all values neither 'X' or 'Y'.

```
SELECT ID,
       DECODE (xy_val,
               0, 'N/A',
               ROUND ((y_val / x_val) * 100)
              ) y_to_x_percent
  FROM (SELECT ID,
               (  DECODE (NVL (col1, 0), 'Y', 1, 0)
                + DECODE (NVL (col2, 0), 'Y', 1, 0)
                + DECODE (NVL (col3, 0), 'Y', 1, 0)
               ) y_val,
               (  DECODE (NVL (col1, 0), 'Y', 1, 'X', 1, 0)
                + DECODE (NVL (col2, 0), 'Y', 1, 'X', 1, 0)
                + DECODE (NVL (col3, 0), 'Y', 1, 'X', 1, 0)
               ) xy_val
          FROM my_table);
```